# Azure Kudu toolbar missing menu items

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm trying to install a site extension to my Azure web app, however my Kudu toolbar only has two menu items, environment and debug console.[image]

Many tutorials about the topic have a site extensions menu item on the toolbar. What should i do to have site extensions on Kudu? My application is a Standard: 1 Small -tier web application.

Comment: can you directly do https://{website}.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions

Comment: It works however on the page there is an error message: Failed to retrieve installed site extensions - An error has occurred. - System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: This is observed if you are web app is using the **Web Apps on Linux**. There are no site extensions supported there.

Comment: @KaushalKumarPanday please make this an answer. Also would be nice to know if there is currently a way to install extensions on Web Apps on Linux if you happen to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kaushal Kumar Panday said, according to your screenshot, you are using Web Apps on Linux, so there is not any site extensions which be ready for Web Apps on Windows.

Web Apps on Linux is a Docker container based on Ubuntu, which you can see it via the tab `Docker Container` on Azure portal and Kudu Debug console with command `uname -a`.

If you need to install more componets or language runtimes, you just need to use Kudu SSH terminal via the url `https://<your linux webapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host` to update the apt source via `apt-get update` and search for you wants via `apt-cache search <keyword for package>` install via `apt-get install <packages of you wants>` like doing these operations on local Ubuntu environment. For more details, you can refer to the offical tutorial [`SSH support for Azure Web App on Linux`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-ssh-support) to know them.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

So as I said, site extensions are not visible if the app is hosted on **[Azure Web App (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-intro)**.

Currently there is no way to get the Site extensions on [Azure Web App (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-intro). You can list all the site extensions here: https://www.siteextensions.net/

Most of the site extensions that exists are mostly written by the community and were mainly written for IIS (Windows). You could however, create a request for this on the [Azure Web Apps feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) site.

I think we should get lot more contributions from the Open Source community to create site extensions for **Azure Web Apps on Linux**.

Comment: I came across this post as I was trying to follow instructions here to set up dynamic ip restrictions:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/dynamic-ip-restriction-for-app-services/ba-p/1150049  Can you suggest an alternative way to set up dynamic ip restrictions on Azure Linux hosted app?

Comment: App service on Linux uses docker container under the hood to provide support for various frameworks. Depending on the underlying distro for the corresponding framework, you can enable something similar. For example if you have .htaccess available, then you can refer the following post: https://htaccessbook.com/block-ip-address/